# Custom Header for a motivation letter

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, letters, headline

I am a little bit new working with LaTeX, I would like to know how to customize Headers in it, I add images that what I like to be able to do.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks for yours answers.

Comment: One would need to know/have access to the `\documentclass` you're using to generate this currently. Do you have a template set up already?

Comment: Which image are you referring to? The background image or the small icons next to address, phone number,...?

Comment: @Werner No, I have not set it up yet. Which one would you suggest me?

Comment: @leandriis I am referring to the image as a set, I mean the background, the icons and also the lines.

Comment: For the icons, the `fontawesome5` package might come in handy. Which documentclass to use also depends on other features you need.

Comment: @leandriis What about the background, any ideas? ... Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun, I propose this solution. This is a hybrid solution, which uses both absolute positioning and a `minipage` for the information on the right. I have used `marvosym` for the symbols but the `awesomefont5` package, as recommended by @leandris, is certainly much more complete (I was not aware of it).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\myblue}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mygray}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}
\newcommand{\myrule}{\color{blue}\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt,opacity=0.03] at (current page.north west)
  {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=8cm]{example-grid-100x100bp}};
\draw[draw=blue,very thick] (0,1.4) -- (7cm,1.4);
\node[anchor=west,text=blue,font=\Large] at (0,1) {John Doe};
\node[anchor=west,text=gray] at (0,0.4) {Digital Marketer};
\draw[draw=blue,very thick] (0,0.1) -- (7cm,0.1);
\node[anchor=west,text=gray,font=\footnotesize] at (0,-0.2) {\today};
\node[anchor=north west,yshift=5mm] at (9,1) 
  {\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
    \raggedleft
    
    John.Doe@gmail.com \myblue{\Email}\\
    202-555-0166 \myblue{\Mobilefone}\\
    ------------ \myblue{*}\\
    ------------ \myblue{*}\\
    ------------ \myblue{*}\\
    ------------ \myblue{*}\\
    ------------ \myblue{*}\\
    \end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that could be a good baseline to work, just a question. How to change the positions of "John Doc / Digital Marker" section?

Comment: "John Doe" is now positioned at (0,1), so you can change the coordinates, for example, to (-1,1.5) and accordingly update the other coordinates. But you could also consider using relative positioning with the `below of=` key.

Comment: Ok, thanks, What about font size?

Comment: The font size is managed by the `\large`, `\footnotesize` and similar commands. I recommend that you consult an introductory guide where these basics are widely covered.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ivan, as I said before, your idea was a great base to work with.
Here I am just putting the code and its changes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5} %https://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/fonts/fontawesome5/doc/fontawesome5.pdf
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{egyptianblue}{rgb}{0.06, 0.2, 0.65}

\newcommand{\myblue}[1]{\textcolor{egyptianblue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mygray}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}
\newcommand{\myrule}{\color{egyptianblue}\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, opacity=0.2] at (current page.north west){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{Conection.png}};

\draw[draw=egyptianblue,very thick] (-3.5,0.4) -- (9cm,0.4);

\node[anchor=west,text=egyptianblue,font=\LARGE] at (-1.5,0) {John Doe};
\node[anchor=west,text=gray,font=\Large] at (-1.5,-0.7) {Digital Marker};

\draw[draw=egyptianblue,very thick] (-3.5,-1.2) -- (9cm,-1.2);

\node[anchor=west,text=gray,font=\footnotesize] at (-1.5,-1.5) {date};

\node[anchor=north west,yshift=5mm] at (12,0.1) 

{\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
\raggedleft

John.Doe@gmail.com \myblue{\faEnvelope}\\
202-555-0166 \myblue{\faMobile*}\\
------------ \myblue{\faMapMarker*}\\
------------ \myblue{*}\\
------------ \myblue{*}\\
------------ \myblue{*}\\
------------ \myblue{*}\\
\end{minipage}};

\end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{2.5cm}

\section*{Intro}
```